# Display one digit percentage, skip fixed numbers vue

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

I have a function that rounds each percentage to 1:

```
items() {
  return this.data
    .map(item => {
      const perc= item.count/ number * 100
      const percentage = parseFloat(perc).toFixed(1) + '%'

      return { ...item, percentage }
    })
    .sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count)
}
```

But the problem is that it rounds also the fixed numbers. For example:

```
100% => 100.0% -> issue
```

So how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if it is a whole number before you round:

```js
const vals = [0,1,1.1,1.1234, 100.0, 100]
const toPercentage = (x) => ((x|0) === x ? String(x) : x.toFixed(1)) + '%'

console.log(vals.map(toPercentage))
```

Try something like this:

```
sortedItems () {
  return this.data
    .map(item => {
      const perc = item.count/ this.smsData.number * 100
      const percentage = ((perc|0) === perc ? String(perc) : perc.toFixed(1)) + '%'
      return { ...item, percentage }
    })
    .sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count)
}
```

(Note that `perc` already is a number, so you don't need `parseFloat()`

Comment: It's great but I cannot seem to include it in my method

Answer (score 1):

You can easily achieve it with [numeraljs](http://numeraljs.com/)

```js
numeral(1).format('0.[0]%') // '100%'
numeral(0.1).format('0.[0]%') // '10%'
numeral(0.56).format('0.[0]%') // '56%'
```

So your code will look like this

```js
sortedItems () {
  return this.data
    .map(item => {
      const percentage = numeral(item.count/this.smsData.number).format('0.[0]%')
      return { ...item, percentage }
    })
    .sort((a, b) => b.count - a.count)
}
```